# nfs(v1.2.8) client does not support all_squash option

Tags: nfs, mount, nfs4

```
$ /sbin/mount.nfs --version
mount.nfs: (linux nfs-utils 1.2.8)
$ mkdir -p ~/mnt && sudo mount -t nfs -o rw,all_squash xx.xx.xx.xx:/lgtm/path/to/share ~/mnt
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

If I remove `all_squash` then it works fine (with the wrong UID/GID obviously). The `all_squash` option was not in `man nfs` either. Was it replaced at some point?

EDIT: my os is Ubuntu 14.04 but `all_squash` doesn't seem to be available on my OS X 10.11 either.

Answer (score 4):

`all_squash` is an [export option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/exports.5.html), to be used on the server.

It's not secure to allow the client to specify how UIDs/GIDs are handled.